# How do I use IKVM from IronPython?

Tags: java, .net, ironpython, ikvm

Let's say I'm writing an app in IronPython and I'd like to use some classes stored in a Java jar (which I don't control and I'd rather not wrap in a DLL).

I downloaded IKVM and tested that command line tools work fine.

Let's say the class I'd like to access is like this:

```
package some.thing;
class Hello {
    public static void myMethod(String arg){
        System.out.println("you got me!");
    }
}
```

Which DLLs should I import from IronPython in order to be able to then call Hello.myMethod('a')?

Is this possible at all with IKVM? If not, is there any other way you can see to make this work?

Comment: Take a look at the IronPython GitHub repository, they have added some IKVM support, but I don't know much about it.